# HABTM related records not being filtered by conditions when using containable

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, containable

Model1 HABTM Model2. In Model1's model class, I have the following code:

```
public class Model1 extends AppModel
{
    function getResult()
    {
        $this->contain('Model2', array(
            'conditions' => array('Model2.name' => 'foo')
        ));
        $result = $this->findByRelatedId($careNoteId);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The result has every related Model2 record. It should only return the Model2 record if that record's name is "foo". No error, the condition is just never added to the SQL.

Containable is declared in AppModel's `actsAs` property.

What gives?

Comment: Can you paste the whole code you are using?

Comment: No, it's a LOT of code. What are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: the context where you are using Containable

Comment: I edited the question to give it more context.

Comment: is Containable already attached in this model? or maybe in AppModel?

Comment: Yes, AppModel contains 'Containable' within its `actsAs` array property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42581/discussion-between-mattalxndr-and-guillemo-mansilla)

Comment: You're missing `=>` on the contain declaration, it should be `'Model2' => array('conditions' => array('Model2.name' => 'foo')`

Comment: I actually figured that out. If you add this as an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong. These syntaxes are correct:

```
        $this->contain(array(
            'Model2' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Model2.name' => 'foo')
            )
        ));
```

or

```
        $this->contain('Model2', array(
            'Model2' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Model2.name' => 'foo')
            )
        ));
```